# Best way to solve coupled PDEs in fipy

Tags: python, fipy

I am trying to solve the following problem using fipy but I am a bit overwhelmed. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

[image]

C and q are the dependent variables and I am solving in 2 dimensions, time (t) and length (z).

Is there any example I can follow? Where should I be looking at in the documentation? Or is there a some other library better suited for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[`examples.diffusion.mesh1D`](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/examples/diffusion/generated/examples.diffusion.mesh1D.html) is the starting point for anybody using FiPy. It runs through the basic concepts of how to set up a problem and it covers the transient and diffusive behavior of your first equation.

[`examples.convection.robin`](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/examples/convection/generated/examples.convection.robin.html) illustrates a static convection-diffusion-source problem with a Robin boundary condition. This covers all the terms on the right-hand side of your first equation and your first boundary condition.

The two equations can either be "swept" in succession until they converge, or they can be coupled. [`examples.diffusion.coupled`](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/examples/diffusion/generated/examples.diffusion.coupled.html) illustrates both approaches for a pair of diffusion equations.

If these aren't enough to get you started, please come back with specific questions about where you're having trouble.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jeguyer. I'm going to start there. I was looking at some of those and wasn't sure they applied to my case. Thanks again.